# Firestore CollectionReference and DocumentReference types missing .add(), .set(), .update(), etc methods

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using Firestore with React and Typescript. I'm trying to get some data from a firestore and update it.
I have seen a lot of examples online using a syntax with methods but my IDE shows that those types don't have these methods.

I am able to get the data from Firestore using functions like this:

```js
import { getFirestore, collection, doc, updateDoc } from 'firebase/firestore';

const firestore = getFirestore(config);

function App() {
  const collRef = collection(firestore, 'collection');
  const docRef = doc(firestore, 'collection/id');
  updateDoc(docRef, { test: 1234 }).then(x => console.log(x));
}
```

But I have seen a lot of examples that chain methods like this:

```js
firebase.firestore().collection('collection').doc('id').set({ test: 1234 });
```

My IDE indicates that none of the types in this chain has any of these methods.
Even the [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#methods) indicates that the Reference types should have the `.get()`, `.set()` and `.update()` methods but they aren't present.

This should be simple but I'm missing something very basic. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The chaining method you are referring to is the older namespaced syntax. The new Modular SDK (`v9.0.0+`) uses the functional syntax as in your first code snippet.

You can still use the older syntax using compat version by changing your imports to:

```
import firebase from "firebase/compat/app"
import "firebase/compat/auth"
// import "firebase/compat/[SERVICE]"
```

However, it's recommended to update your code to new syntax to get benefits of tree shaking. Checkout the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade) for more information.